# Associations - getting values according to a key pattern

Tags: associations, regular-expressions

I want to get all counts of trigrams that with "th" (or any other given digram).

```
humanRights = 
  ToLowerCase@ExampleData[{"Text", "UNHumanRightsEnglish"}]; 

trigramCounts = LetterCounts[humanRights, 3];
```

How can I do this? Neither `trigramCounts["th"<> _]`, `trigramCounts[["th" ~~ _]]` nor `trigramCounts[RegularExpression["th*"]]` produce the desired effect

Comment: All the values are trigrams. Therefore I think the pattern "th"~~_ is sufficient and the anonymous function becomes StringMatchQ[#, "th" ~~ _]&

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way:

```
KeySelect[trigramCounts, StringMatchQ[#, "th" ~~ ___] &]
```